# Using WindowsForm on Visual Studio c# 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, layout

Good evening everyone!
 i have made this question because when i increase the left or right side from a Windows Form, the tabControl dont move together with it.

That maybe a property that i couldnt find yet, can you guys help me?

Thanks for all

Answer (score 3):

see Dock & Anchor property of windows form and spliter control

Answer (score 2):

You need to set tab's Anchors property to either left or right - which ever side you want to move with the form.

Answer (score 1):

See the Anchor Propery..

If you want to resize the tabcontrol with the resizing of the form anchor it on every-side..

If you want to fill the form with the tab control, or stick the tabcontrol to one margin, use Dock Property...

Answer (score 1):

Set the Form.Dock Property to true